# I want to execute specific test cases say for Ex: TC5 and TC10 using TestNG?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

When I have 10 automation test cases and I want execute specific test case like TC5 and TC10. How to acheive this using TestNG?

Answer (score 0):

From [Running tests in TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng)

> TestNG can be invoked in different ways:
>
> - Command line
> - [ant](http://testng.org/doc/ant.html)
> - [Eclipse](http://testng.org/doc/eclipse.html)
> - [IntelliJ's IDEA](http://testng.org/doc/idea.html)

With those 4 links you should be able to get the appropriate documentation for whichever way you want to run. Each one documents how to run select methods, classes, packages, and groups.

You can also define a [`testng.xml`](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml) file which includes/excludes the methods/classes/packages/groups you want to run. e.g.:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
  
<suite name="Partial-TC-Suite">
  <test name="TC5+TC10">
    <classes>
       <class name="com.example.test.TC5"/>
       <class name="com.example.test.TC10"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use enabled=false to the test to skip execution.

@Test(enabled=false)

public void Skip(){

System.out.println("This testcase is skipped");

}